# how to handle click or change event for radiobuttonfor in mvc3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a simple user registration form. The user can be registered as a company or individual. Following is the relevant view for the Registration form that uses RadioButtonFor html helper. I have defined the id property to be used in the javascript:

```
    @model LayoutTest.ViewModels.ProjectUser
    <script>
    $(function () {
    $("#Class_UserType").change(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value == 1) {
            $('#Person').hide();
        }
        else if (value == 2) {
            $('#Company').hide();
        }
      });
    });
    </script>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Project", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
   @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
   <fieldset>
   <div class="new_row">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.UserType)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.UserType, (int)UserType.Company, new { @id= "Class_UserType" }) Company
                @{Html.ValidateFor(model => model.UserType);}
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.UserType, (int)UserType.Individual, new { @id = "Class_UserType" }) Individual 
                @{Html.ValidateFor(model => model.UserType);}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Company">
          HTML Tags inside
    </div>
    <div class="Person">
        HTML Tags inside
    </div>
```

This code should hide the respective divs Company/Person, when working correctly. I have looked at numerous samples but cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here! Any help will be appreciated.

Following is the relevant html output:

```
    <div class="new_row">
        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="UserType">*User Type</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <div class="editor-field">
                <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field *User Type must be a number." data-val-required="The *User Type field is required." id="Class_UserType" name="UserType" type="radio" value="1" /> Company
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <input checked="checked" id="Class_UserType" name="UserType" type="radio" value="2" /> Individual 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following did the trick for me:

```
    $('.UserType').change(function () {
        var value = $(this).filter(':checked').val();
        if (value == "1") {
            $('.Person').hide();
            $('.Company').show(500);
        }
        else if (value == "2") {
            $('.Company').hide();
            $('.Person').show(500);
        }
    });
```

Firstly, I needed to define a common class as per below in my html:

```
    <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.UserType, (int)UserType.Company,  new { @id= "Class_UTCompany", @class="UserType" }) Company
                @{Html.ValidateFor(model => model.UserType);}
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.UserType, (int)UserType.Individual, new { @id = "Class_UTIndividual", @class="UserType" }) Individual 
                @{Html.ValidateFor(model => model.UserType);}
     </div>
```

Secondly, I was expecting the value in int, and that was causing the error. I was able to find that by putting debugger; in my javascript code.